# Range of possible $x_{k}$'s in log-sum-exp function

Tags: summation, exponential-function

Suppose I am given a list of floating-point values $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$. These quantities are shown in the log-sum-exp given here:

$l(x_1,...,x_n)$ = $ln(\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{x_k})$

The value $p_{k}$ = $e^{x_{k}}$ represents a probability, which means that $p_k$ is in the set (0,1]. In this case, what is the range of possible $x_{k}$'s?

Can't $x_{k}$ from the $e^{x_k}$ part just be any number? Isn't the range simply $x_1$ to $x_n$ or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_k = e^{x_k}$ and $p_k \in (0,1] \implies e^{x_k} \in (0,1] \implies \ln(e^{x_k}) \in (\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \space \ln(x), \ln(1)]\implies x_k \in (-\infty, 0] = \mathbb{R}^- \cup \{0\}$

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, thank you!